# Replace Window History title with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using `history.replaceState(null, "historyTitle", "url")` in my solution to replace the URL of a page to something more human-readable. The problem that I am facing is that, although it replaces the URL, and navigating back in the browser goes to the correct page, the `"historyTitle"` part seems to be ignored within chrome - it instead adds the entire URL as the page location in the window history instead of just using the title. How can I overcome this to display "historyTitle" in my browser history for that specific page I landed on?

Small Edit: I am using this in conjunction with a custom route I set up within MVC, so even changing the title, followed by refreshing the page, the MVC router still navigates to the correct page. It's only the title in the window history (ctrl+H) within chrome which doesn't update the title properly and dumps the entire page URL within that record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed this is a bug, although intentional for 2 years now. The problem lies with some unclear specs and the complexity when `document.title` and back/forward are involved.

See bug reference on [Webkit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=43730) and [Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=585653). Also Opera on the introduction of History API said it wasn't using the title parameter and probably still doesn't.

> Currently the 2nd argument of pushState and replaceState — the title
>   of the history entry — isn't used in Opera's implementation, but may
>   be one day. Potential solution

The only way I see is to alter the title element and use pushState instead:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML = 'bar';
window.history.pushState( {} , 'bar', '/bar' );
```

Comment: hmm but this adds an overhead issue that if you press the browser back button, it will first modify the url, then you need to press it again for the browser to actually go back - hence the reason I followed on replaceState

Comment: However, it seems to erratically fix the issue with the browser history entry title, by setting the document title with javascript. This is odd